# how to clean string data

Tags: python, pandas

I extract values from pandas and for number values I embarrass in bracket `float(num)` which return only integer.

However when I request a string object like:

`a.subject` - it returns

```
20    Math
Name: Class10, dtype: object
```

howe to get only `Math` without the rest in more efficient way?

Comment: What is `a` Can you add some sample data?

Comment: a is df- dataframe

Comment: OK, can you add sample data?

Comment: Can you show the output of `type(a)` and `type(a.iloc[1, 2])` ?

Comment: a is df and subject is the column where I get value 'Math'. But when I return it it gives me 20    Math
Name: Class10, dtype: object

Comment: Use: `df.loc['Class10','subject']`

Comment: I just want to get only Math. When I return number I can put float() and it return number without  type and etc

Comment: @on Clements type(a)  pandas.core.series.Series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is one element `Series`, so instead `a.subject` select by index and columns labels by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
a.loc['Class10','subject']
```

Or [`DataFrame.at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html):

```
a.at['Class10','subject']
```

Or if you want first value of `subject`:

```
a.loc[a.index[0], 'subject']
```

Or:

```
a.iloc[0, a.columns.get_loc('subject')]
```

Also is possible select by column name and then by position:

```
a.subject.iat[0]
a.subject.iloc[0]
a.subject.to_numpy()[0]
```

If possible `a.subject` is sometimes empty, selecting failed. Then use:

```
next(iter(a.subject), 'no match')
```

Comment: the data I get is from input which I define as class based on class it goes to pandas and get value . So left index is class like Class10 based where I request find subject for the class which should return Math.

Comment: your code does not work with input data-customised way

Answer (score 0):

Use `at` to return only the value:

```
import pandas
import numpy

a = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.randn(5,1),columns=['subject'])

print(a)
print(a.at[1, 'subject'])
```

result:

```
    subject
0 -0.010719
1  0.908645
2 -0.552890
3 -0.756518
4 -0.831926

0.908645173602986
```